# How to make IntelliJ 2021 format single-line throwing lambda as in IntelliJ 2020?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ code style format definition published at https://github.com/airlift/codestyle/blob/f20834967969cdafce461ee203788e567f842e1e/IntelliJIdea2019/Airlift.xml

IntelliJ 2020.3.4 (and I think all previous versions I used) would format single line throwing lambda like this

```
Consumer<String> unimplemented = value -> { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); };
```

While formatting the above, IntelliJ 2021.2.3 removes spaces inside curly braces:

```
Consumer<String> unimplemented = value -> {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();};
```

How to make IntelliJ 2021.2.3 format the code the way older versions did?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Code Style settings, go to the "Spaces" tab and find "Within -> Code Braces". Turn it on.

[image]

Or if you want to edit the code style XML directly, you can add:

```
<option name="SPACE_WITHIN_BRACES" value="true" />
```

in the block

```
<codeStyleSettings language="JAVA">
    ...
</codeStyleSettings>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for the question as written. Yet, I forgot to add that I need an empty code block (empty lambda, empty function definition), to be formatted as `{}`, without spaces.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen You can ask a new question, but I don't think there is a setting for that. See [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-style-java.html) for the list of settings.

Comment: That would mean intellij changed default formatter behavior with no way to restore previous. Not practical for existing codebases being collaborated on by many people naturally using different IDE versions.